# Split string with multiple special characters using JS or Regex

Tags: javascript, split, query-string

I have the following URL queryString `index.html?cars=honda+nissan&price=90+60+70` and need to remove all the characters `=, +, &`. When I chain the split it returns `split is not a function`

Desired output;

```
honda
nissan
90
60
70
```

JS:

```
const urlSearch = window.location.search;
const param = urlSearch.split('=')[1].split('&');
```

Comment: See [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_API) to iterate over the `searchParams` instead.

```js
const str = 'http://index.html?cars=honda+nissan&price=90+60+70';

const params = new URL(str).searchParams;

for (const [key, value] of params.entries()) {
  value.split(' ').forEach(el => console.log(el));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define what part of query you want to use and also you should use the queries this way

```
const urlSearch = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const param = urlSearch.get("cars").split('=')[1].split('&');
```

for more information about getting query string check out here https://flaviocopes.com/urlsearchparams/

in your case you want to split the strings of car in the query string but you didn't mention to get it and then use it, so the data will be undefined and when you want to call a function on an undefined value it will throw following error

```
(FUNCTION)* is not a function
```

it can be anything such as `map` function or anything else